# Ubuntu Components - Picker problem

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml

While trying to create two pickers on Ubuntu inside a dialog, the labels inside can only be read properly when they are not chosen and overlap on the left when chosen, as seen in the image:

[image: Ubuntu Picker problem]

The code for the dialog:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

import Ubuntu.Components 1.1
import Ubuntu.Components.Pickers 1.0
import Ubuntu.Components.Popups 1.0

Component {
    id: dialogComponent

    Dialog {
        id: dialog
        objectName: "dialog"

        HospitalsModel {
            id: hospitalsModel
            objectName: "hospitals_model"
        }

        PrimaryCenterModel {
            id: primaryCenterModel
            objectName: "primaryCenter_model"
        }

        title: i18n.tr("Configuration")
        text: i18n.tr("Please, choose your hospital and primary center")

        Picker {
            id: hospitalPicker
            objectName: "hospitalPicker"

            model: hospitalsModel
            delegate: PickerDelegate {
                Label {
                    fontSize: "x-small"
                    text: name
                }
            }
        }

        Picker {
            id: primaryCenterPicker
            objectName: "primaryCenterPicker"

            model: primaryCenterModel
            delegate: PickerDelegate {
                Label {
                    fontSize: "x-small"
                    text: name
                }
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: okBtn
            objectName: "okBtn"

            text: i18n.tr("OK")
            onClicked: PopupUtils.close(dialog)
        }
    }
}
```

The hospitals model:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

ListModel {
    ListElement {
        name: "Hospital El Bierzo"
        url: "http://www.saludcastillayleon.es/HBierzoPonferrada/es"
    }

    ListElement {
        name: "Hospital Serranía Ronda"
        url: "http://www.malagasalud.es/hospitales-publicos-en-malaga/hospital-serrania-ronda-area-sanitaria-serrania-malaga,112.html"
    }
}
```

The primary center model:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

ListModel {
    ListElement {
        name: "Centro de Salud 2, Pico Tuerto"
        url: "http://www.jcyl.es/web/jcyl/Portada/es/Plantilla100Directorio/1248366924958/0/1142233519857/DirectorioPadre"
    }

    ListElement {
        name: "Centro de Salud Ronda-Sur, Santa Bárbara"
        url: "http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/servicioandaluzdesalud/centros/detalle.asp?IdCentro=24967"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix this issue so the chosen labels are readable?

Comment: This is definitely a sdk theming bug. That said, I would recommend not using a dialog for your purpose. A dialog is meant to be compact and used mostly for yes/no questions. I would highly recommend using a new page to show those option selectors.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the Dialog, you would get the same problem no matter where in what context is used.

From the code I see you are using a circular Picker, which uses a PathView to visualise the model. PathView stretches the delegates based on the amount of the data in the model, thus the behaviour you see. Try to set circular to false, I'm sure the visual will be ok then.